# Can a Quadro P2000 support 12 1080p monitors via the use of 4 port MST hubs?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-quadro, mst

I am looking at driving a video wall made of a 3x4 grid of 1080p monitors.  Looking a card like the Quadro P2000, it says it can drive 4 5k monitors.  Using display port MST technology, is it possible to put a 4 port MST hub on each display port output to be able to drive all of the monitors with a single card?  Would there be any screen tearing issues, and would nVidia Mosaic technology still be available?  Is there a benefit to doing this over using multiple lower tier cards (Such as the P600)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it would not work. If you take a look into the [quadro p2000 datasheet](http://images.nvidia.com/content/pdf/quadro/data-sheets/301941-DS-NV-Quadro-Pascal-P2000-US-03Feb17-NV-fnl-WEB.pdf)
There is the following information:

**Max Simultaneous 
Displays:**
4 direct, 4 DP 1.4 
Multi-Stream

Depending on how this is ment to be interpreted you can have either up to 4 or up to 8 monitors connected to this card. For more information and some professional recommendations I suggest you contact NVIDIA support.

Comment: Fixed the link ^^